# how to get layer from the map in libgdx (TiledMapTileLayer)

Tags: java, android, libgdx

```
Map map;
public void Create(){
    map=new TmxMapLoader().load("map.tmx");  
} 

public TiledMapTileLayer.Cell remove(){
    TiledMapTileLayer tileid = (TiledMapTileLayer) map.getLayers().get(2);
    return tileid.getCell((int)(body.getPosition().x*100/16),(int)((body.getPosition().y*100/16)));
}
```

i want to get layer which is 2 yes i'm sure its a layer not an object 
and yes i start counting from 0
and i created the body which works good 
all my code works fine but when i add `TiledMapTileLayer tileid = (TiledMapTileLayer) map.getLayers().get(2);`

im sure that the problem is whith this line but idk what is it
`TiledMapTileLayer layer = (TiledMapTileLayer) map.getLayers().get(2);`

the problem:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mygdx.game.MyGdxGame.remove(MyGdxGame.java:420)
    at com.mygdx.game.MyGdxGame.onhit(MyGdxGame.java:415)
    at com.mygdx.game.Sensor.Sencor.endContact(Sencor.java:42)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.endContact(World.java:990)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.jniStep(Native Method)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.step(World.java:689)
    at com.mygdx.game.MyGdxGame.render(MyGdxGame.java:253)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:225)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:126)
```

Comment: What error do you get when you try that?

Comment: Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: And you are sure the exception is thrown on that line? That means either map or map.getLayers() is null.

Comment: Does map draw?.

Comment: yes it does draw

Comment: show full exception

Comment: @icarumbas i didnt make an exception. is it necessary? i dont know how to

Comment: "Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException" what's after this line?

Comment: ohh.. i did add it up above

Comment: Maybe this line `    return tileid.getCell((int)(body.getPosition().x*100/16),(int)((body.getPosition().y*100/16)));
` why you multiple by 100/16

Comment: because i want to scale it up because i scaled every thing down in ppm and 16 is the size in pixles of the box that i want im not sure tho but i have removed them then thats what i got

Comment: Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.mygdx.game.MyGdxGame.remove(MyGdxGame.java:420)
 at com.mygdx.game.MyGdxGame.onhit(MyGdxGame.java:415)
 at com.mygdx.game.Sensor.Sencor.endContact(Sencor.java:42)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.endContact(World.java:990)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.jniStep(Native Method)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.step(World.java:689)
 at com.mygdx.game.MyGdxGame.render(MyGdxGame.java:253)
 at

Comment: com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:225)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:126)

Comment: Try to access layer using it's name. `map.getLayers().get("nameOfLayer")`

Comment: here what i wrote` map.getLayers().get("bricks");`

Comment: Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.mygdx.game.MyGdxGame.onhit(MyGdxGame.java:415)
 at com.mygdx.game.Sensor.Sencor.endContact(Sencor.java:42)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.endContact(World.java:990)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.jniStep(Native Method)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.step(World.java:689)
 at com.mygdx.game.MyGdxGame.render(MyGdxGame.java:253)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:225)
 at

Comment: com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:126)

Comment: i have tried it like this
`public TiledMapTileLayer.Cell remove(){
 TiledMapTileLayer layer = (TiledMapTileLayer) map.getLayers().get(3);
 return layer.getCell(10,10);

}`

im sure the problem is with this line
`TiledMapTileLayer layer = (TiledMapTileLayer) map.getLayers().get(3);`